# How do I add reCaptcha to my WordPress.com blog?

Tags: wordpress.com

Question is in the title.  What are the specific steps involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know today that is not possible. Wordpress.com uses [Askimet](http://akismet.com/) to protect you from spam.

Comment: It is also more reliable.

Comment: Askimet is the worst thing you can do in the sense of data security. It just sends everything home.
Oh and you can try this: Adding a "spam"-looking comment using some e-mail address which you do not typically use. Wait for it as being marked as spam. Now you can't leave any comment using this e-mail address anymore (no matter from which computer and IP) on any blog using Askimet. Malicious people can use it to block your address.

Comment: I don't think Askimet is bad at all, I like it. On my blog the accuracy rate is 99.448%. One 719 comments, it failed 4 times.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [reCaptcha plugin](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/plugins/wordpress) for self-hosted WP sites. You [cannot add plugins to WP.com sites](http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/).